# How does Stadia implement long press Escape key to exit full screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to capture Escape Key on full screen on Chrome and not exit fullscreen from the same. Stadia seems to have long press escape to exit from full screen instead of just escape. How can this be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I think they are using the experimental [Keyboard Lock API](https://github.com/WICG/keyboard-lock)

Comment: Indeed, you can learn more about the API in this [article](https://web.dev/keyboard-lock/).